# Django Inner Join Queryset where there is no foreign key relation between two tables

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-queryset

Please Help !
I Want to know the inner join Queryset for the below mentioned raw oracle Query : -

select PubC.component,PubC.comp_version,PubC.publish_id,PubEv.published_date from PubEv
inner join PubC
on PubC.publish_id = PubEv.publish_id 
where 
PubC.target_branch = 'polaris_dev' and PubC.component = 'aaa' 
order by PubEv.published_date desc;

And the models mentioned in the django project are as follows:-

```
class PubEv(models.Model):
    vob = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    target_branch = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    publish_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    target_branch_label = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    main_release = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    published_by = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField()
    publish_ddts = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    unpublished = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    changeset = models.ForeignKey('CcChangesets')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'publish_events'

class PubC(models.Model):
    publish_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    vob = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    target_branch = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    component = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    comp_version = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'publish_contents'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to do that within the Django ORM. You'll be much better off if you make that a `OneToOne` relationship than attempting to keep them as unrelated, primary key fields.